# React dropzone uploader with meteor gives error_upload though image preview appears OK

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, meteor, dropzone

I'm trying to upload image files to an AWS S3 bucket, in my Meteor / React app.

I'm using [React Dropzone Uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start).

Versions:

```
METEOR@1.8.1
"react": "^16.11.0"
"react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0"
```

Everything except the S3 bucket itself is running on my local development machine.

When I drag an image onto the dropzone uploader in the browser, I see the progress bar and then the image preview, but the console shows the message "error_upload" and the "Submit" button is disabled.

According to the [docs](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/api) error_upload is set if upload response has HTTP status code >= 400, but I don't understand what that means. The image preview looks fine, the url has been generated correctly, and I haven't yet tried to perform the actual upload to AWS.

As far as I can see everything is happening in the right order: the client console logs my signedUrl in this form:

```
signedUrl in client https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test/DA8acSgM3wQtrReEK/userpic.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=somekeyid&Expires=1576600622&Signature=somestuff
```

before then logging 'uploading' and displaying what look like valid object details:

```
height: 100
​id: "1576600322132-0"
​lastModifiedDate: "2014-01-21T17:00:42.000Z"
​name: "userpic.jpg"
​percent: 0
​previewUrl: "blob:http://127.0.0.1:3000/80aaa9bd-b7b8-492e-8e13-8c8b971e4998"
​size: 5203
​status: "uploading"
​type: "image/jpeg"
​uploadedDate: "2019-12-17T16:32:02.137Z"
​width: 100
```

then finally the client console shows:

```
error_upload
height: 100
​id: "1576600322132-0"
​lastModifiedDate: "2014-01-21T17:00:42.000Z"
​name: "userpic.jpg"
​percent: 100
​previewUrl: "blob:http://127.0.0.1:3000/80aaa9bd-b7b8-492e-8e13-8c8b971e4998"
​size: 5203
​status: "error_upload"
​type: "image/jpeg"
​uploadedDate: "2019-12-17T16:32:02.137Z"
​width: 100
```

Here's my code:

client:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-dropzone-uploader/dist/styles.css';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone-uploader';

const callWithPromise = (method, myParameters) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Meteor.call(method, myParameters, (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject('Something went wrong');

            resolve(res);
        });
    });
};

const DropzoneUploader = ({ docId }) => {
    const getUploadParams = async ({ meta }) => {
        const signedUrl = await callWithPromise('getUploadParams', { 'key': `test/${docId}/${meta.name}` });
        console.log('signedUrl in client', signedUrl);
        return { 'url': signedUrl };
    };

    // called every time a file's `status` changes
    const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta, file }, status) => { console.log(status, meta, file); };

    // receives array of files that are done uploading when submit button is clicked
    const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
        console.log(files.map((f) => f.meta));
        allFiles.forEach((f) => f.remove());
    };

    return (
        <Dropzone
            getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
            onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*"
        />
    );
};

export default DropzoneUploader;
```

Server: aws.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

AWS.config.update({ 'accessKeyId': accessKeyId, 'secretAccessKey': secretAccessKey });

const myBucket = process.env.AWS_BUCKET;
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;

const getSignedUrl = (key) => s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    'Bucket': myBucket,
    'Key': key,
    'Expires': signedUrlExpireSeconds,
});

export default getSignedUrl;
```

server: methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
'getUploadParams': function ({ key }) {
        const signedUrl = getSignedUrl(key);
        console.log('signedUrl on server', signedUrl);
        return signedUrl;
    },
});
```

CORS configuration on bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I'll be very grateful for any help as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Update: the Network tab is showing Status code 403 forbidden 'SignatureDoesNotMatch' for a call to my signedUrl, which surprised me since I didn't think it would try to upload the file until the user clicks "Submit" in the browser. So maybe the problem is with my AWS credentials? But I'd like to know exactly what is happening with the url request at this stage.

Update 2: I've changed my s3.getSignedUrl function to specify 'putObject' instead of 'getObject', but it's still not working. I can see from the Network tab that the request is actually being sent as POST but I can't figure out how to change that?

Comment: im having the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I never got it working. In the end, I used the old Meteor plugin edgee:slingshot@0.7.1 (https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot) which works like a charm.